# Multiple select not working

Tags: php, jquery

I have a `select` options form to update profile data for users, but running this code is update only the first variable. Any solution please? Thanks in advance and here is my code:

```
JQ(function($) {
    $("#Nazione,#Regione,#Etta,#Altezza,#Peso").on("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/aggiornaProfilo.php",
            cache: false,
            data: $("#Nazione,#Regione,#Etta,#Altezza,#Peso").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                $("#res").delay( 600 ).fadeIn( 300 ).html('<img src="css/loaders/loader1.gif">');
            }
        })
        .done(function(respN) {
            $("#res").fadeOut('fast');
            $.pnotify({
                icon:false,
                sticker: false,
                text:respN
            });
        })
    });
});
```

and the php part is->

including array for select option

```
DataArrays();

global $Nazioni,$Regioni,$Etta,$Altezza,$Peso,$Corporatura,$Seno;

$Naz = @$_POST["Nazione"];
$reg = @$_POST["Regione"];
$ett = @$_POST["Etta"];
$alt = @$_POST["Altezza"];
$pes = @$_POST["Peso"];
$cor = @$_POST["Corporatura"];
$sen = @$_POST["Seno"];



if(isset($Naz)){
        $validateNaz = array_search($Naz, $Nazioni);
        if($validateNaz){
            if(mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE profili SET Nazione='$Naz' WHERE user='$userSession' LIMIT 1")){
                echo 'nazione aggiornata con successo';
            }else{
                echo 'errore';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'errore';
        }
    }else
if(isset($reg)){
        $validateReg = array_search($reg, $Regioni);
        if($validateReg){
            if(mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE profili SET Regione='$reg' WHERE user='$userSession' LIMIT 1")){
                echo 'regione aggiornata con successo';
            }else{
                echo 'errore1';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'errore2';
        }
    }else

    if(isset($ett)){
        $validateett = array_search($ett, $Etta);
        if($validateett){
            if(mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE profili SET Etta='$ett' WHERE camgirl_profilo='$userSession' LIMIT 1")){
                echo 'etta aggiornata con successo';
            }else{
                echo 'errore etta';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'errore etta';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain properly what you are trying to do and what the problem is. Your code does not even declare any variables, so I don't know what "the first variables" should be.

Comment: What is your html ? And better way is, repace all id's to one class.

Comment: I can see any select options

Comment: More questions: Where is the code of `/ajax/aggiornaProfilo.php` that is the place where you actually run the database query?!

Comment: on change option run js ajax to aggiornaProfilo.php where i have the code like this if(isset($nazioni)){ validate and update }else if(isset($regione)){ validate and update } you understand?

Comment: No i don't. Please add the code to your question instead of copying it into a comment... (All the code that is necessary and no pseudo scripting language)

Comment: Each time I see both PHP and JS code I interpret it as a clear sign that you haven't taken effort to localize the problem. Have you at least verified that one of them is working? 1) Have you tried to feed the PHP script with custom input and check the output of the script? 2) Have you tried to drive the JS code with some hardcoded JSON data (so that you don't do an ajax call)?

Comment: if i make ajax request for nazioni and after another for each of them i works but the code is too long and i want to makeit much clean

Comment: 1. you should DRY your code a lot [i.e. there is much repetition, plust too many nested `if` blocks]; 2. you should not write code in native language - I can understand it, but others may not [by others I mean future colleagues / SO users]; 3. you should use prepared statements in your queries.

Comment: i dont open a post to asking for prepared statement....

Comment: @Alex: You open a post to ask us for help. And if there is someone trying to point out that your script might be insecure you can be glad and should thank him!

Answer (score 0):

**You should most definitely write code in english.**

If i understand your php code correctly it is clear why only the first value is updated in the db.

This is because of your if/elseif construct. So if the first condition is true no other will be executed.

Change this to three if conditions and it should work if there is no other error.

```
if(isset($Naz)){
    $validateNaz = array_search($Naz, $Nazioni);
    if($validateNaz){
        if(mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE profili SET Nazione='$Naz' WHERE user='$userSession' LIMIT 1")){
            echo 'nazione aggiornata con successo';
        }else{
            echo 'errore';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'errore';
    }
}

if(isset($reg)){
    $validateReg = array_search($reg, $Regioni);
    if($validateReg){
        if(mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE profili SET Regione='$reg' WHERE user='$userSession' LIMIT 1")){
            echo 'regione aggiornata con successo';
        } else {
            echo 'errore1';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'errore2';
    }
}

if(isset($ett)){
    $validateett = array_search($ett, $Etta);
    if($validateett){
        if(mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE profili SET Etta='$ett' WHERE camgirl_profilo='$userSession' LIMIT 1")){
            echo 'etta aggiornata con successo';
        } else {
            echo 'errore etta';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'errore etta';
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this to three what do you mean?

Comment: sorry about the language...now i give a try to se if it works

Comment: it update only a couple of select and return like was updated all

Comment: I do not understand you. Give some clear information what works and what doesn't. Show example data and the desired result you would like to have.

Comment: if i set the php like this    global $Nazioni,$Regioni,$Etta,$Altezza,$Peso,$Corporatura,$Seno;

$Naz = $_POST["Nazione"];
$reg = $_POST["Regione"];
$ett = $_POST["Etta"];
$alt = $_POST["Altezza"];
$pes = $_POST["Peso"];
$cor = $_POST["Corporatura"];
$sen = $_POST["Seno"];

   if(mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE profili SET Nazione='$Naz',Regione='$reg',Etta='$ett',Altezza='$alt',Peso='$pes',Corporatura='$cor',Seno='$sen' WHERE camgirl_profilo='$userSession' LIMIT 1")){
    echo 'nazione aggiornata con successo';
   }else{
    echo 'errore';
   }
it works but how do i validate if the option selected

Comment: is valid from the array and is not modified